# Excel - stacked chart bar doesn't build up new records from 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I would like to prepare the stacked bar chart in Excel. Unfortunately, the problem I encounter is that data aren't populated from 0, but they are added up to already plotted values like you can see below:

[image]

Whereas I would like to build up something like suncalc as below:

[image]

If I would be able to plot every value from the beginning and overlap other values, which are already in, I could do it.

I tried this method, but I failed

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4840-excel-bar-chart-overlap-gap-width.html

Is there any way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following is what you want:

1. Insert a clustered bar chart

[image]

2. Select then right click on one of the bars, then choose "Format Data Series" from the drop-down menu

[image]

3. Set the series overlap to 100%

[image]

Note: You may need to change the order of the series in the Data Source dialog box for all the bars to be visible

[image]

The final result should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@cybernetic.nomad has described your situation, but I thought another slice at chart types might help illustrate the issue.

Stacked charts do just that, stack the values on top of each other. The illustration below shows the difference between clustered and stacked bar charts. The default stacked chart (bottom right) is what you created, and you can see as I reduce the overlap from 100% to 50% to zero, the bars start where the previous bar ends. The default clustered chart (top left) shows the values side by side, each one starting at zeri. As the overlap changes from zero to 50% to 100%, you can see how the shorter bars in front can obscure the longer bars, giving you the chart you want.

The method you cited encourages this approach, but it was not very clear, and it added a lot of extraneous gibberish.

[image]